# why would these two queries return different counts?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

this query returns 125000 total for `[Specimen ID]`

```
; with cte (rejected) as 
(

select distinct([specimen id])
from QuickLabDump
where  DATEPART(mm, [DATE entered]) = 01
and DATEPART(yyyy, [DATE entered]) = 2012
and QuickLabDump.Outcome='REJECTED'

)


    select [Specimen ID],max([Order Count]) from QuickLabDump
    left outer join cte
    on QuickLabDump.[Specimen ID]=cte.rejected
    where DATEPART(mm, [DATE entered]) = 01
    and DATEPART(yyyy, [DATE entered]) = 2012
    and cte.rejected is  null
    group by [Specimen ID]
    order by 2 desc
```

whereas if i do the same count on the `Specimen ID` here, i get around 127000:

```
; with cte (rejected) as 
(

select distinct([specimen id])
from QuickLabDump
where  DATEPART(mm, [DATE entered]) = 01
and DATEPART(yyyy, [DATE entered]) = 2012
and QuickLabDump.Outcome='REJECTED'

)

select 
    [Full Date]=CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), [DATE entered], 1),
    [Year Entered]=DATEPART(yy, [DATE entered]) ,  
    [Month Entered]=LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH, [DATE entered]), 3),
    [Day Entered]=DATEPART(dd, [DATE entered]),
    [DOW]=
       case when DATEPART(WEEKDAY, [DATE entered])=1 THEN 'Sun'
       when DATEPART(WEEKDAY, [DATE entered])=2 THEN 'Mon'
       when DATEPART(WEEKDAY, [DATE entered])=3 THEN 'Tus'
       when DATEPART(WEEKDAY, [DATE entered])=4 THEN 'Wed'
       when DATEPART(WEEKDAY, [DATE entered])=5 THEN 'Thu'
       when DATEPART(WEEKDAY, [DATE entered])=6 THEN 'Fri'
       when DATEPART(WEEKDAY, [DATE entered])=7 THEN 'Sat'
       end,
    [Week Ending]=CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),
        DATEADD (D, -1 * DatePart (dw,[date entered]) + 6, [date entered]), 1),
    [CountAccns]=count(a.[specimen id]),
    [Sales Rep]=c.salesrep,
    [MLNPI]=c.npi,
    [IMSNPI]=e.npib,
    [IMS Specialty Primary Code]=e.SpecialtyPrimaryCodeb,
    [IMS Specialty Secondary Code]=e.SpecialtySecondaryCodeb,
    [IMS Specialty Tertiary Code]=e.SpecialtyTertiaryCodeb,
    [IMS Professional ID 1]=e.ProfessionalID1b,    
    [Physician]=[Requesting Physician],
    [Practice Code]=a.[practice code],
    [MLIS Code]=b.[mlis practice id],    
    [practice name],
    [Date Established]=c.dateestablished , 
    [Address]=c.practiceaddress1, 
    [Address2]=c.practiceaddress2,
    [City]=c.practicecity,
    [State]=c.practicestate,
    [Status]=b.[Active Inactive],
    [order count]=a.[order count]
from 
    quicklabdump a
    left outer join qlmlismapping b on (b.[practice code] = a.[practice code])
    left outer join PracticeandPhysician c on 
        a.[Requesting Physician]=c.doctorfirstname+' '+c.DOCTORLASTNAME 
        and a.[practice code]=c.practicecode
    left outer join IMSData e on c.NPI=e.npib
    left outer join cte
        on a.[Specimen ID]=cte.rejected

where    
     DATEPART(mm, [DATE entered]) = 01
    and DATEPART(yyyy, [DATE entered]) = 2012
    and cte.rejected is null

group by 
    a.[DATE entered],
    c.salesrep,
    c.npi,
    e.npib,
    e.SpecialtyPrimaryCodeb,
    e.SpecialtySecondaryCodeb,
    e.SpecialtyTertiaryCodeb,
    e.ProfessionalID1b,
    a.[Requesting Physician],
    a.[practice code],
    b.[mlis practice id],
    [practice name],
    c.dateestablished , 
    c.practiceaddress1, 
    c.practiceaddress2,
    c.practicecity,
    c.practicestate,
    b.[Active Inactive],
    a.[order count]
 having a.[order count]=max([order count])
    order by  [Practice Code] desc,Physician desc
```

why is there such a tremendous difference with the count? wouldnt you think that it would be exactly the same since both queries are supposed to return the same total amount of `Specimen IDs`?

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the culprit!

In the second query i was doing   `[CountAccns]=count(a.[specimen id]),`

this in fact should have been:

```
[CountAccns]=count(distinct(a.[specimen id])),
```

the two counts now lined up!!

Answer (score 1):

Right off the bat I can see several factors that could be causing different record counts between the two queries:

1. In your first query you are only grouping by `SpecimenID` in the second query you are grouping by many more attributes.
2. Your second query includes a few extra joins which could easily result in different result counts
3. Your second query includes a `Having` predicate, which the first query doesn't

Comment: thank you so much for your answer! can you please tell me why would grouping by more attributes change the result counts?

Comment: yes there are extra joins, but they are all LEFT OUTER JOINS and just return NULL if there is no data

Comment: the first query selects specimen ID and max([Order Count]), the having clause on the second query does the same thing doesnt it? - thank you again so much for your input and help

Comment: @!__ - if there is a one-to-many relationship, this could potentially increase the count regardless if it is a left join or not

Comment: @!__ - as far as grouping, think about it this way: group the names in a phone book by last name, now group them by last name, first name - the more attributes you group by, the more distinct groups you are likely to have

Comment: thank you. can you please show me an example of whena left join would increase the count? im not understanding. also thank you for the group by explanation, that makes sense to me.

Comment: @!__ - the `HAVING` clause is predicate that applies a *filter* after the grouping has been applied - whereas the `SELECT` does not apply any kind of filter

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7575/discussion-between-i-and-j-cooper)

Answer (score 1):

Is [specimen id] nullable? If so I would try the following in both queries:

1. `Set ansi_nulls on`
2. To the cte's in both queries add `AND [specimen id] IS NOT NULL`
3. In the first query, alias QuickLabDump as `a`
4. Remove `left outer join cte...` (both queries)
5. Remove `and cte.rejected is null` (both queries)
6. Add `and not exists(select 1 from cte where [specimen id]=a.[specimen id])` to the where clauses in both main queries.

Updated code follows

```
-- First Query  
set ansi_nulls on

; with cte (rejected) as  
(  
    select distinct([specimen id])  
    from QuickLabDump  
    where  DATEPART(mm, [DATE entered]) = 01  
    and DATEPART(yyyy, [DATE entered]) = 2012  
    and QuickLabDump.Outcome='REJECTED'  
    and [specimen id] is not null  
)  
select [Specimen ID],max([Order Count])  
from QuickLabDump a  
where DATEPART(mm, [DATE entered]) = 01  
and DATEPART(yyyy, [DATE entered]) = 2012  
and not exists(select 1 from cte where rejected=a.[Specimen ID])  
group by [Specimen ID]  
order by 2 desc  
go  

-- Second Query  
set ansi_nulls on  
; with cte (rejected) as   
(  
    select distinct([specimen id])  
    from QuickLabDump  
    where  DATEPART(mm, [DATE entered]) = 01  
    and DATEPART(yyyy, [DATE entered]) = 2012  
    and QuickLabDump.Outcome='REJECTED'  
    and [specimen id] is not null  
)  
select   
    [Full Date]=CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), [DATE entered], 1),  
    [Year Entered]=DATEPART(yy, [DATE entered]) ,  
    [Month Entered]=LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH, [DATE entered]), 3),  
    [Day Entered]=DATEPART(dd, [DATE entered]),  
    [DOW]=  
       case when DATEPART(WEEKDAY, [DATE entered])=1 THEN 'Sun'  
       when DATEPART(WEEKDAY, [DATE entered])=2 THEN 'Mon'  
       when DATEPART(WEEKDAY, [DATE entered])=3 THEN 'Tus'  
       when DATEPART(WEEKDAY, [DATE entered])=4 THEN 'Wed'  
       when DATEPART(WEEKDAY, [DATE entered])=5 THEN 'Thu'  
       when DATEPART(WEEKDAY, [DATE entered])=6 THEN 'Fri'  
       when DATEPART(WEEKDAY, [DATE entered])=7 THEN 'Sat'  
       end,  
    [Week Ending]=CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),  
        DATEADD (D, -1 * DatePart (dw,[date entered]) + 6, [date entered]), 1),  
    [CountAccns]=count(a.[specimen id]),  
    [Sales Rep]=c.salesrep,  
    [MLNPI]=c.npi,  
    [IMSNPI]=e.npib,  
    [IMS Specialty Primary Code]=e.SpecialtyPrimaryCodeb,  
    [IMS Specialty Secondary Code]=e.SpecialtySecondaryCodeb,  
    [IMS Specialty Tertiary Code]=e.SpecialtyTertiaryCodeb,  
    [IMS Professional ID 1]=e.ProfessionalID1b,      
    [Physician]=[Requesting Physician],  
    [Practice Code]=a.[practice code],  
    [MLIS Code]=b.[mlis practice id],      
    [practice name],  
    [Date Established]=c.dateestablished ,   
    [Address]=c.practiceaddress1,   
    [Address2]=c.practiceaddress2,  
    [City]=c.practicecity,  
    [State]=c.practicestate,  
    [Status]=b.[Active Inactive],  
    [order count]=a.[order count]  
from   
    quicklabdump a  
    left outer join qlmlismapping b on (b.[practice code] = a.[practice code])  
    left outer join PracticeandPhysician c on   
        a.[Requesting Physician]=c.doctorfirstname+' '+c.DOCTORLASTNAME   
        and a.[practice code]=c.practicecode  
    left outer join IMSData e on c.NPI=e.npib  
where    
     DATEPART(mm, [DATE entered]) = 01  
    and DATEPART(yyyy, [DATE entered]) = 2012  
    and cte.rejected is null  
    and not exists(select 1 from cte where rejected=a.[Specimen ID])  
group by   
    a.[DATE entered],  
    c.salesrep,  
    c.npi,  
    e.npib,  
    e.SpecialtyPrimaryCodeb,  
    e.SpecialtySecondaryCodeb,  
    e.SpecialtyTertiaryCodeb,  
    e.ProfessionalID1b,  
    a.[Requesting Physician],  
    a.[practice code],  
    b.[mlis practice id],  
    [practice name],  
    c.dateestablished ,  
    c.practiceaddress1,  
    c.practiceaddress2,  
    c.practicecity,  
    c.practicestate,  
    b.[Active Inactive],  
    a.[order count]  
 having a.[order count]=max([order count])  
    order by  [Practice Code] desc,Physician desc  
go
```

Comment: thanks so much for your help can you please show me the resulting query?

Comment: your query yielded the same exact results as my query